# AJAX - fetch information from a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Based on this link 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

This can fetch data on the database using combo box, by using change event. 
Now what I'm trying to do is to load the data, after pressing the submit button.

This is my codes when I fetch the data using change event, This is working,

```
 $("#cal_country").change(function(){
        var str = document.getElementById("cal_country").value;
        var str1 = document.getElementById("country_year").value;
        var str2 = document.getElementById("country_month").value;



      var foo = $("#cal_country").val(); 
      if(foo)
      {  
         $("#sortHolidayWrapper").css({"visibility":"visible"});

      } 

        if (str=="")
        {
          document.getElementById("holiday_display").innerHTML="";
            return;
          } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
              document.getElementById("holiday_display").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        var url = holiday_preview_vars.plugin_url + "?id="+str+"&cy="+str1+"&cm="+str2;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 


      });
```

I tried to change the

```
$("#cal_country").change(function(){
```

to

```
$("#submit").submit(function(){
```

But its not working,. any idea for this one?

**EDIT**

```
$('#submitHoliday').submit(function(){
    $.get('holiday_preview_vars.plugin_url',$('#submitHoliday').serialize(),function(response){
        console.log(response);
      var str = document.getElementById("cal_country").value;
    var str1 = document.getElementById("country_year").value;
    var str2 = document.getElementById("country_month").value;


    if (str=="")
    {
      document.getElementById("holiday_display").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
          document.getElementById("holiday_display").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }


    var url = holiday_preview_vars.plugin_url + "?id="+str+"&cy="+str1+"&cm="+str2;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    $("#holiday_display").html(response);

    });
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: I assume `#submit` is a submit button. If so it should be `$("#submit").click(function(e){`, but make sure to prevent the default action -> `e.preventDefault();` inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#formId').submit()` will do the trick, but you also have to `return false` to prevent the form from submitting and send the data by ajax.

```
 $('#formId').submit(function(){
    $.get('holiday_preview_vars.plugin_url',$('#formId').serialize(),
       function(response){
        console.log(response);
       //your code to process response
         $("#holiday_display").html(response);
    });
    return false;
 });
```

Btw, `$.get` is jQuery's short hand for `$.ajax` get method. You can replace most of your code with this snippet

Comment: uhm.. submit button stores data, also I want to make it as an event that display the form just like the change event. I tried this one, but it does not display the data.

Comment: edited, it should now display the result as per your code, be sure to replace `formId` with the id of your form

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it right,. can you check my codes. Thanks

Comment: You used the formID right? not the submit button id?

Comment: yes, its the form that has the submit event to which you can attach

Comment: I just saw your edit, you can delete all of your code and replace it with the above snippet. `$.get` does the same as everything from `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)` to `xmlhttp.send(); ` I'm assuming you included jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you prevent the default action of the form to allow your AJAX call to proceed:

```
$("#submit").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // the rest
```

Also, probably not a good idea to have a form with the ID `submit`.

Comment: I don't think the form does have an id of submit, he just assumes that the submit button has a submit event